# Alpha in Fragment Shader gl_FragColor not working

Tags: three.js, glsl

I'm using Three.js and a ShaderMaterial to draw Points Geometry with a Fragment Shader.

I want each point to have a blurred edge, but I can't get the alpha to work, it just turns white.

I can discard pixels when they're completely transparent to make a circle, but the blur fades to white and is then abruptly cut off.

Here's what I see on screen: [image: What I see on screen]

Three.JS code

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
      uniforms:     uniforms,
      vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,
      blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
      depthTest: true,
      transparent: true,
      clipping: true
    });

    var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, shaderMaterial);
```

Fragment Shader:

```
//translate gl_PointCoord to be centered at 0,0
vec2 cxy = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;

//calculate alpha based on distance from centre
//(I'm doubling it to get a less gradual fade) 
float newAlpha = (1.0-distance(cxy, vec2(0.0,0.0))) * 2.0;

if (newAlpha < 0.01)
{
    //discard pixels that have ~0 alpha
    discard;
}

gl_FragColor = vec4( newR, newG, newB, newAlpha);
```

Thanks in advance for any help :) This has been puzzling me for AGES.

Edit: Images of depthTest on and off. It looks to me like depth test does put them in the right order?

depthTest false: [image: depthTest:false]

depthTest true: [image: depthTest:true]

Comment: I believe the problem here is that you have `depthTest: true` in your material. Since the order at which your particles is drawn is set by the vertex position on geometry instantiation, the particles aren't rendered back to front. Leading to incorrect rendering.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment - I think they are rendering in the right order though. I tried setting it to false and it looks very weird but the order looks correct when set to true.

Comment: I can see from the image you provided that they aren't being rendered back to front, cause some particles render as expected and others don't. And I know that Three.js doesn't sort the vertices of a mesh before rendering, just the objects on the scene.

Comment: Weird how? Is it possible to provide a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/u0q459p8/) for easier debugging?

Comment: Just added images of depthtest true/false. I'll try to get something on jsfiddle

Comment: Oh ok, I see the problem here already. `depthTest: false` won't work indeed. In reality, you don't want to show the occluded particles anyway, but the rendering order problem stays. I don't think there's an easy fix. Making the particle a flat color and discarding pixels outside of the circle is probably your best bet here.

Comment: Is there a completely different way to do this then? I was hoping to have a kind of bokeh effect with particles in and out of focus depending on their depth.

here's a live demo if useful: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanplackett/Lt1kmp7v/

Comment: Bokeh DoF doesn't actually blurs the outline of the particles. You just need to control the opacity and the enlargement of the particle based on their depth. Also, using a different blending might be necessary for visual fidelity. I've implemented this exactly behavior on my [Atomize](https://sciecode.github.io/) experiment. You can check the source code.

Comment: Why is there an alpha component to gl_FragColor then if it doesn't actually make things transparent?

Comment: It makes things transparent. You may need to study how transparent objects are rendered in a rasterizing pipeline. The problem is that the rendering expects the objects to be rendered from the deepest to shallowest. Which can't be guaranteed in this scenario, which, in turn, leads to these artifacts.

Comment: the dots do look like they're in the right order though - nearest are on top

Comment: Every non occluded particle will be rendered correctly. But if they are drawn first, the z-buffer will prevent the particles behind it from being rendered. Which makes it seem like the transparency isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSFiddle example has several instances where it fights with itself. You're trying to set the material blending mode in Three.js, but then you override that with:

```
var gl = renderer.context;
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

You're requesting an `animationFrame`, but then do a setTimeout inside of that, removing all benefits of using `animationFrame`.

I was able to get something slightly improved with

```
blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
transparent: true,
depthWrite: false,
depthTest: true
```

You can see the fixes live here: https://jsfiddle.net/yxj8zvmp/

... although there are too many attributes and uniforms being passed to your geometry to really get to the bottom of why the depth isn't working as expected. Why are you passing `u_camera`, when you already have [cameraPosition](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram), and your `position` attribute is of length `1`? It feels like a blend of raw WebGL fighting with Three.js.

Comment: He posted this link in your conversation above: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanplackett/Lt1kmp7v/

Comment: yeah I missed his fiddle somehow.

Comment: just wanted to point out that settting `depthWrite: false`, in a scene with no other objects, is the exact same effect as to what I first suggested with `depthTest: false`. I know @marquizzo knows this, but others might not.